# Compilling and install libnettle 3.7 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: compiling, filezilla, gnutls

I need to compile and install **libnettle 3.7** on **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**. I need it to compile and install GnuTls 3.7 and libfilezilla 0.35 and FileZilla 3.57. So, I downloaded **nettle-3.7.3.tar.gz**. Configure, make and install. And just to be sure

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib64/
```

Bu when I configure GnuTLS from sources **gnutls-3.7.2.tar.xz** I get

```
checking for NETTLE... no
configure: error: 
  ***
  *** Libnettle 3.6 was not found.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to install it on Ubuntu 20.04?

---

Answering to @steeldriver

There are two files in `/usr/local/lib64/pkconfig`: **hogweed.pc** and **nettle.pc**.

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/ pkg-config --cflags --libs nettle` returns:

`-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib64 -lnettle`

BTW Synaptic shows that libnettle 3.5.1 is installed.

Comment: Unless you modified the ./configure `PREFIX`, then it looks like nettle installs everything in /usr/local - in particular, the .pc file goes in /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/. What does `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/ pkg-config --cflags --libs nettle` return?